# converting existing ios app to universal application

Tags: ios

I need help on following topic.

I have an existing iPhone app (which I believe was created with "specific device" in mind). Now I want to convert it to "universal" app? Is it possible?

Finally, at some places there were also suggestions that one could create separate iPhone and iPad apps (in case of complex applications). I am not sure if this is what I want, since: I want my iPad and iPhone apps to *share* some code and at the same time to achieve "universal" functionality. What is the best way to do this? ps. so to sum up I would prefer to have it all in single project if this is possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Gregory, as much I think you're talking about universal app. I suggest you, before go ahead you need to google, there are so many materials you'll find.

In short, for your case, you need to prepare two XIBs each for iPhone and iPad respectively and you've to exchange them that depends on your device. So, your code part will be same, but what will alter is the representation part ie IBs.

In any concern, just get back to me. :)

Comment: thanks. I already have an iPhone app. I must also add iPad support to it, and it seems I will have to rewrite viewcontrollers etc. for the iPad version as some web sites mention (e.g., apple web site). the problem is that sometimes in the existing code certain functions are used which maybe were specific for iPhone, and for iPad I may need to call a different method -- the question is how to I differentiate between two modes? e.g., in one case I call one method, in another a different method? Is it done using #defines, etc?

Comment: You can get the detail about device using UIDevice check it.

Comment: so, you suggest I have one project for iPhone (which I already have), add new viewcontrollers for iPad -- and then depending on which device I am using, call respective functions right? thanks.

Comment: Hi, and also just one thing. This link: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html mentions that when I create a new project I have to select whether it is "universal" or device specific. What I can't clear out from the web site, is, if I already created a device specific project, can I change its preferences so that it becomes "universal"? do you know if its possible? thanks

Comment: yeah, you can do by changing it's type in project plist and one morething you don't required to make another controller file besides you need to make different IB file one for iPhone and another one for iPad and in your common controller file you need to tell which IB will be used...like if I navigate then... ClassA *objA = [[ClassA alloc] initWithNibName:@"Here-You-Tell-About-IB"]; then..[[self navigationController] pushViewController:objA animated:YES];...Hope, now you can get...

Comment: hi thanks. also after google-ing i will rephrase my question a bit so that it's more clear.